# I need to copy the input given by the user to the child Process. How can I copy the input given to child processes stdIn?

Tags: go

I need to copy all the input provided by the user for the child process during its execution. I have tried to scan the cmd.Stdin for the copy of  input but can't get it. Am I missing something here?

```golang
func main(){
  cmd:= exec.Command("python", "-i")
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

  buff := bufio.NewScanner(cmd.Stdin)

  go func(){
    for buff.Scan(){
      fmt.Println(buff.Text())
    }
  }()

  _ = cmd.Run()  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll actually need to capture the input, and pass it to the subprocess...

```
func main(){
  cmd := exec.Command("python", "-i")
  stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

  buff := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

  go func(){
    for buff.Scan(){
      input := buff.Text()
      fmt.Println(input)
      io.WriteString(stdin, input)
    }
  }()

  cmd.Start()  
  cmd.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Python interpreter needs a new line at the end of each input. By appending the new line at the input it worked.